# Autohide Media Controls SilverLight Player

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, controls, media-player

I am trying to get my media controls to auto hide after 2 seconds. However the way I have it set up is that it only works when my mouse leaves the StackPanel I have the media controls in. And if I keep moving the in and out of the StackPanel then it will start to flicker as it is firing the hide even multiple times.  I am unsure on how to go about this logically. Anyone have any tips or suggestions?

Here is what I got right now (StackPanel is named controls).

```
...
controls.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(control_unhide);
controls.MouseLeave += new MouseEventHandler(control_hide);
...

void control_hide(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    var miniTimer = new DispatcherTimer() { Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2) };
    miniTimer.Tick += (s, i) => { miniTimer.Stop(); controls.Opacity = 0; };
    miniTimer.Start();

}
//Unhide controls
void control_unhide(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    controls.Opacity = 100;

}
```

Also from some sample code I have seen people say to use Collapse and Visible to make the controls hide and reappear. This however doesn't work as the Collapse seems to make the boundaries unresponsive to the mouse entering.

Thanks!

****Edit

I asked this question because I spent a lot of time trying to figure this out yesterday only to sit down today and think of a really easy solution.  What I did was this:

```
//global
private DispatcherTimer hideTimer;

....
//init
hideTimer = new DispatcherTimer() { Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2) };
hideTimer.Tick += (s, i) => { hideTimer.Stop(); controls.Opacity = 0; };
hideTimer.Start();

controls.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(control_unhide);
controls.MouseLeave += new MouseEventHandler(control_hide);
...


void control_hide(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    hideTimer.Start();
}

//Unhide controls
void control_unhide(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{

   controls.Opacity = 100;
   hideTimer.Stop();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution would be to put in a guard variable and only hide if you weren't currently hiding:

```
bool currentlyHiding;

void control_hide(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (!currentlyHiding)
    {
        var miniTimer = new DispatcherTimer() { Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2) };
        miniTimer.Tick += (s, i) =>
            {
                 miniTimer.Stop();
                 controls.Opacity = 0;
                 currentlyHiding = false;
            };
        miniTimer.Start();

        currentlyHiding = true;
    }
}
```

You will also need to do something similar for the unhide.